# Deserialize JSON class to Java class of different name

Tags: java, json, gson

My previous question on this didn't really get anywhere, and maybe I wasn't asking the right thing or it was too detailed.

My basic question is now, how I can I deserialize a JSON object with one class name, to a Java object with a different class name?

For example, the JSON class the server sends/expects is "18" (I have zero control over this). My Java class can't be "18", so it's "_18".

Simply doing new Gson().fromJson() didn't help, even with different naming policies; the _18 object is always null. I have since read about type adapters and different annotations, but am still unclear on how to approach this. The method that seemed the most sensible, @SerializedName, apparently can't be used for the class itself, just field members.

How can I deserialize a JSON object with a class called 18, to a Java class called _18 (or, better yet, if it's possible, I can give the class a real name)?

Sample JSON, by request:

```
"18": {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "field3": "value3"
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the JSON you are dealing with?

Comment: Sample JSON added in edit.

Comment: Use a Map<String, ClassWithThreeFields>: "18" will be the key of the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - JSON has no conception of class - it is a string representation of an object.
So, your example is just a malformed JSON. It must be like:

```
{"18":
 {
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2",
  "field3": "value3"
  }
}
```

That is valid JSON object with field "18" as of another class with `field1`,`field2` and `field3` properties in its turn.

so, if server returns JSON string like your show - to parse it you have to surround it with {} and then your Java class will have property for "18" as you want to name it for Java by `@SerializedName` annotation.

see the sample test case below:

```
public static  void main(String... args) throws Exception {

    String testJson = "{\"18\":{\"name\":\"poomba\",\"value\":\"topchoomba\"}}";

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    MyClassFor18 test18 = gson.fromJson(testJson, MyClassFor18.class);

    System.out.println(test18);

}

private static class MyClassFor18 {

    @SerializedName ("18")
    private TestPojo valueObject;

    public TestPojo getValueObject() {
        return valueObject;
    }

    public void setValueObject(TestPojo valueObject) {
        this.valueObject = valueObject;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "MyClassFor18 (value=" + valueObject + ")";
    }

}
private static class TestPojo {

    private String name;
    private String value;

    public TestPojo(String name, String value) {

        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "TestPojo { name=" + this.name + ", value=" + this.value
                + "}";
    }
}
```